# Is it possible to embed multimedia (audio or video)?

Tags: embedding, animations

Using TeX/LaTeX is it possible to embed multimedia?
If so how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`movie15`](http://ctan.org/pkg/movie15) package to do this in pdfLaTeX. Simple usage:

```
\includemovie{<movie file>}
```

But often it's more complex. See the manual for details.

Comment: The complexities include that whatever pdf viewer is being used needs to "know" how to run the movie, and this is very much an application- and OS-dependent thing.

Comment: There's also some detail about this in the beamer manual.

Comment: I was never able to get this working. It doesn't seem to work with `evince`, for instance, although I think it works with Adobe Reader.

Comment: @rberraldo: Adobe Reader with some plug-in (installed on Windows by default) is needed.

Comment: As some stated above, I also didn't got it managed in Ubuntu 11.04 nor Windows 7, both with TexLive2011 and Adobe Reader 9.3 or 9.4. Isn't there a tutorial which actually works?