# LaTeX generated alternative to PDF with multimedia support?

Tags: pdf, audio

Is there some alternative to PDF or PostScript, which is good for publishing documents written in LaTeX and support video and/or audio?

Comment: Maybe iTeX, described in [this announcement from Knuth](http://river-valley.tv/media/conferences/tug-2010/Don-Knuth/) will do what you want (I haven't tried to use it myself).

Comment: HTML, also maybe using some Flash-based SW like the one on http://www.scribd.com, ..., I think that's it. PDF seems to be the best way. Why? What's your issue with it?

Comment: I'm thinking about methods to publish text with video.

Comment: @scdmb: PDF support that, see [Is it possible to embed multimedia (audio or video)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17900/is-it-possible-to-embed-multimedia-audio-or-video).

Comment: @scdmb: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Lev Bishop: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-on-earth-is-itex

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to drop the PDF format in order to have audio/video support. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17900/is-it-possible-to-embed-multimedia-audio-or-video/17902#17902) on how to embed a movie in a PDF with LaTeX.