# What on earth is iTeX?

Tags: tex-core, knuth

Is that an hoax?

Or is it a real wish from D. Knuth?

(http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/media/conferences/tug-2010/Don-Knuth)

Comment: The proposal is based on a number of claims which might make sense for some commercial mogul to make, but which are absolutely outlandish coming from Knuth: claims that he's a lousy programmer, claims that no-one should trust anything more than 30 months old, claims that they have anticipated all of the possible wishes of the user, *etc.* This coming from a man who wrote TeX in the first place, and the author of the modern epic saga The Art Of Computer Programming. After 20 minutes or so, it is extremely obvious that it's a hoax.

Comment: Oh well, that's better :)

Comment: @Niel: It took you 20 minutes to catch on to the joke?

Comment: @Harald: no, I pulled that number out of may hat. Even before he got to the name `eee-TECKS <bell ringing>` there was a rather implausible list of features. It could be that even his remarks on `0.4pt = 0.39999pt` could have been a tip-off if I knew enough TeX-lore, but just at the **very** beginning it was not obvious.

Comment: @Niel: That should teach you not to pull numbers out of a hat. Yeah, I admit it took me a while to catch on too, but my numbers will remain in the hat.

Comment: @Harald: well, I said that it was extremely obvious after 20. I didn't say that it was totally unobvious prior to the 19.5 minute mark. My mistake for being imprecise, I suppose.

Comment: @Niel: So you did. Good point.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is a joke. Knuth is known for his "professional humor", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Humor.

Comment: He is hilarious XD I was laughing all the way through XD

Comment: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Answer (score 18):

All i components of Apple are presented in San Francisco, where also the last TUG meeting (32 years of TeX) was held. This was the reason why Knuth introduced the iTeX in his talk with an *audio visuell* logo ... It was a joke ...

Comment: And let's not forget that the bell ringing is _also_ part of the iTeX logo! =)

Comment: That _is_ the _audio_ part of the label.

Comment: Oh sorry, I got it now. =)

Comment: don't forget the 3d logo-embossed glass bowl part, all set in a hyperbolic plane, where the geometry allows you to put as much content as you want as close together as you want...

Answer (score 16):

It's worth documenting that there is another, non-joke, *iTeX*.

WebTeX was a restricted subset of LaTeX that was designed for rendering as webpages, offering a more sophisticated layout model than CSS.  Paul Gartside took a subset of that focussed on rendering mathematics, called it iTeX, and wrote a converter to MathML, which he called itex2mml.

Jacques Distler is currently maintaining itex2mml, and provides documentation of [the iTeX language](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/itex2MMLcommands.html) and [the itex2mml utility](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/itex2MML.html).

Answer (score 7):

Well, there is another non-joke iTeX, an iPad reader for documents prepared with TeX/LaTeX.  It's in the iTunes app store, and you can read about it at
http://itex.cheswick.com
or see my presentation on it at the same conference as Knuth's i(whistle)TeX,
but I beat him by two days.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: While it's usually fine to promote one's own products or developments on tex.sx, you should be a little more clear that it's your project.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought the link would suffice, without an excess of self-trumpeting.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bit late april's fools :)