# Origin and formation to the ERROR ‘Dimension too large’

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

When I tried to compile:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin, red] (0,0) circle (2);
\foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, ..., 46} \draw[very thin, red] ({360 * \i / 100}:1) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 

l.6 ...thin, red] ({360 * \i / 100}:1) circle (1);

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

And if I turn `46` to `45`, say `\foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, ..., 45}`, that code will pass the compiling.

It seems that some value I was trying to calculate is larger than the TeX engine can handle.

After searching TeX.SX for about half an hour, I got [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33082/how-can-i-avoid-the-dimension-too-large-error-when-plotting-in-newer-pgf-versi), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/tikz-when-i-use-the-draw-let-in-command-to-draw-a-trivial-arc-i-get-dimens) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118487/dimension-too-large). These questions have been solved, however, the origin and structure of the problem still remain unclear. Hence, I decide to raise this question: what is the limit (its origin and formation), and how can I avoid it.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: By default TikZ uses TeX dimensions, and dimensions must be in the range `-16384 < x < 16384`. It doesn't matter if the result of the entire calculation is in this range. If the range is exceeded at any point there will be an error. In this case you can reorder the calculation: `(\i/100*360:1)`.

Comment: @MarkWibrow That deserves to be an answer. :)

Comment: @MarkWibrow: Thank you! But what does TeX mean by '19 feet'? Can you tell me where can I find that range?

Comment: @Alenanno: Absolutely! But I want to know more. :)

Comment: Change the order of operations: 
replace `({360 * \i / 100}:1)` with `({ \i / 100 * 360}:1)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TeX dimen arithmetic is fixed point arithmetic, based on integer arithmetic of *scaled points* `sp`.  2^{16}sp=65536sp=1pt .

The maximum dimension that may be stored is saved in plain TeX and LaTeX as `\maxdimen` and is 2^{30}sp = 16384pt ~ 18.9ft.

Basic arithemetic (as implemented by `\dimexpr` for example) each subterm in the calculation, not just the final answer, needs to be within +/- `\maxdimen`.

Floating point packages such as `fp` or `l3fp` can handle floating point values and larger ranges but do so by avoiding TeX dimen registers and maintaining the values in macros and doing the calculations "by hand".

As well as limiting the absolute value this conversion to integer `sp` arithmetic limits the accuracy, for example 360/100 will be coded as 360pt/100  is 65536*360sp / 100  which already in integer arithmetic can not be calculated exactly. For use in typesetting measurements rounding error of a few `sp` are literally invisible to the eye so irrelevant however if TeX arithmetic is used for more extensive calculations these issues can arise, as you found.

Comment: could you (perhaps) add the value of the maximal dimension in the metric system inherited from the French revolution? :)

Comment: @jfbu I only ever think of it in pt but there was a question about feet from the OP:-) but `\maxdimen` is ~ 5758.3mm

Comment: Related: some (most?) of these limitations are mentioned in [the humorous presentation of Donald E. Knuth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-on-earth-is-itex)