# How to increase the \foreach number in tikz

Tags: foreach

```
   \foreach \z in {0,1,...,150}{
    \draw [fill=black] (\z, {add(101/add(1,2*\z),-\z*\z/add(1,2*\z))}) circle (1pt);}
```

Dimension too large.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139906/73383

In your case, the problem is that the magnitude of `-\z*\z` is too large. It is however easily solved by adding parentheses around `\z/add(1,2*\z)` like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \z in {0,1,...,150}{
    \draw [fill=black] (\z, {add(101/add(1,2*\z),-\z*(\z/add(1,2*\z)))}) circle (1pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it useful :)
(see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)