How to Use the Function from @AlainMatthes (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58735/278762) with 50 Teeth?
how to use the function from @AlainMatthes (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58735/278762) with n=50 teeths?
Code:
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first 

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
  [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
             -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
}}  


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[thick] \gear{50}{2}{2.4}{10}{2};
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document} 

Result:


Another solution would be https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318140/36296

The (\i -1)*360 goes out of range for TeX numbers. Do the division before the multiplication: (\i-1)*(360/#1):
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first 

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
  [rotate=(\i-1)*(360/#1)]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
             -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
}}  


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[thick] \gear{50}{2}{2.4}{10}{2};
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document} 

But I'm not sure about the parameters, you get this:


thx a lot also with explanation :)

You could change the order of the caclulations a bit to avoid the numbers getting too big:
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first 

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
  [rotate=(\i-1)/#1*360]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
             -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
}}  


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[thick] \gear{55}{2}{2.4}{0}{2};
 \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document} 



thanks a lot for your help here

@MarcoMoldenhauer You're welcome!
