# Plotting Power Functions like x^-2, x^-3 etc

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have been looking all over the Exchange and online to try to find how to plot functions like `1/x^3`. I get an error in the dimension. I am using the `\addplot` command under tikz. I have tried different domains but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize, yshift=0.6ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize, xshift=0.5ex}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Negative Integer Powers}

The graphs of power functions that have negative integer exponents have \emph{two} distinct shapes (see Figures 3 and 4 below).

\begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
grid style={blue!50},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
ymin = -5,  ymax = 5,
xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
grid = both,
]
\addplot[samples=300,domain=-3:3,ultra thick,color=blue]{1/(x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$y=x^n$ $\bigcup$-shaped}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
grid style={blue!50},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
ymin = -5,  ymax = 5,
xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
grid = both,
]
\addplot[samples=300,domain=-3:-0.1,ultra thick,color=blue]{1/(x^3)};
\addplot[samples=300,domain=0.1:3,ultra thick,color=blue]{1/(x^3)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Graph of $y=x^{-3}$ or $y=1/x^3$}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

It worked, but the dimensions and figures don't align.

Nick

Comment: That's probably because you can't find the image of null. Try to draw it between -3 and -0.0001 and another one from 0.0001 and 3. Actually, it's almost what you did.

Comment: Didn't work. Thank you though for taking time to comment

Comment: They talk about the "dimension too large" error in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/origin-and-formation-to-the-error-dimension-too-large
Given that 0.1^(-3)=1000 and that is bigger than the maximun TeX can handle (around 576), it throws an error. Try with ```domain=-3:-0.2``` and ```domain=0.2:3``` and it should be fine.

Comment: Remember math at school. What is 1/x^n for x = 0? Do not blame Latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pgfplots` package. The error `dimension too large` is avoided by use of `restrict y to domain`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\pgfplotsset{
    axis lines=center, 
    grid,
    grid style={very thin, blue!50},
    xmin=-5,    xmax=5,         xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ymin=-5,    ymax=5,         ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    restrict y to domain=-10:10, % <-------
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    domain=-4:4, samples=100,
    no marks, 
    every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick, semitransparent, color=magenta,},
            }
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[declare function = {f(\x)=1/((\x)^2);}] % or f(\x)=1/(\x*\x);
\addplot    {f(x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph of $y=x^{-2}$ or $y=1/x^2$}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[declare function = {f(\x)=1/((\x)^3);}] % or f(\x)=1/(\x*\x*\x);
\addplot    {f(x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph of $y=x^{-3}$ or $y=1/x^3$}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Zarko!

Comment: @NIckBennett, you are welcome! BTW, instead to say  thank you, you should vote answer (by clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answer) or even accept it, if from all received answer the best fit your expectation (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer). As I see it, so far you have not accept any from the gotten answers. Did no one meet your expectations?

Comment: Not that. Just didn't realize I could do that.

Comment: Sigh, can't I convince anyone to use \x*\x instead of \x*2?  Even when it works right, it is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, see comments in code at definition of functions `f(\x)` ;-)

Comment: @Zarko - Ah, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

`Dimension too large` is an annoying error. In most cases, you can use Asymptote (better accuracy) to avoid it. I give below an incomplete solution using plain TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Negative Integer Powers}
The graphs of power functions that have negative integer exponents have \emph{two} distinct shapes (see Figures 3 and 4 below).
\vspace*{3mm}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw[blue!50] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
\path[nodes={scale=.8,fill=white}] 
(\i,0) node[below]{$\i$}
(0,\i) node[left]{$\i$};
\draw[-stealth] (-5,0)--(5,0);
\draw[-stealth] (0,-5)--(0,5);
\begin{scope}
\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[magenta,smooth,ultra thick]
plot[domain=-3:-.2] (\x,{1/(\x*\x)})
plot[domain=.2:3] (\x,{1/(\x*\x)}); 
\end{scope}

\path (current bounding box.south) node[below]
{Figure 3: $y=x^n$ $\bigcup$-shaped};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw[blue!50] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
\path[nodes={scale=.8,fill=white}] 
(\i,0) node[below]{$\i$}
(0,\i) node[left]{$\i$};
\draw[-stealth] (-5,0)--(5,0);
\draw[-stealth] (0,-5)--(0,5);
\begin{scope}
\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[magenta,smooth,ultra thick]
plot[domain=-3:-.2] (\x,{1/(\x*\x*\x)})
plot[domain=.2:3] (\x,{1/(\x*\x*\x)}); 
\end{scope}
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below]
{Figure 4: Graph of $y=x^{-3}=1/x^3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```