# How to draw a general graph in TIkz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to graph something similar to the picture posted.

[image]

I am having trouble. I am a novice Tikz user but can't seem to figure out how to plot a general equation for a function.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,thin](-0.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right]{$t$};
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,thin](0,-1.5)--(0,3.5) node[right]{$j(t)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is your code relevant for the graph? Do you want the text placed somewhere on the graph? Please show some code trying to do the graph. You could start from your own graph here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585730/8650

Comment: I am sorry. I had the wrong code copied. I fixed it.

Comment: Please edit the question to make is readable. You can not insert the image in the middle of the code.

Answer (score 3):

One more solution using `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb]
\draw[->]   (-0.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {time (hours)};
\draw[->]   (0,-0.5) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$j(t)$};
\draw[->, thick]    (0,2.5) .. controls +(2,0) and + (-2,0) .. (3.5,0.5)
                    node[midway,above right] {$j(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that I have not spent hours using those resources, or spending time looking through other posts? I try to find solutions to problems before I post. My posts are usually done because I can't find a solution to what I am working on.

Comment: Dear @NickB, in your question you say "I am a novice Tikz user ...", so I try to help you where you can find information about "plot a general equation " (whatever this mean)". It seems that this you find offending.  I'm very sorry for this. I will delete my *note* by which I try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As you do not have any function for the graph, I assume you do not care. Here is one way to draw the curve:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,thin](-0.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right]{$t$};
\draw[Triangle-Triangle,thin](0,-1.5)--(0,3.5) node[right]{$j(t)$};
\draw[-Triangle] (0,2.5) to[out=0, in=90] (1.5,1.5) to[out=-90, in=180] (3,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph of curve]

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure what the full code means, but I can look at it in depth later.

Comment: `to[out=-90, in=180]` means draw a curve leaving the preceding coordinate at an absolute angle of `-90` (horizontal) to the next coordinate entering at an angle of `180` (vertical). Try changing the number to see what they do.