# !Dimension too large error apple silicon M2

Tags: graphics, pstricks, pst-plot

i have just bought the new macbook air M2. I've tried to compile a file i had before and i had the message "!Dimension too large error". I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore.
here is the code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[scaled=0.875]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,makeidx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp,enumitem}
\usepackage[table,dvips]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-tree,pst-func,pstricks-add}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=1.9cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=0.0005cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1000)(10.5,24000)
\multido{\n=0.0000+0.3333}{32}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.2pt](\n,0)(\n,23000)}
\multido{\n=0+1000}{24}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.2pt](0,\n)(10.5,\n)}
\psaxes[linewidth=1.25pt,Dy=2000]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(10.5,23000)
\uput[r](0,23500){Nombre de mégots}\uput[d](9.25,-800){Rang de l'année}
\uput[d](10.5,-300){$x$} \uput[l](0,23000){$y$}
\psdots[dotstyle=+,linecolor=red,dotscale=2](0,20000)(1,17384)(2,14817)(3,12569)(4,10721)(5,9142)(6,8458)(7,7673)(8,6691)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I get the error on TeXlive 2021 on Linux as well, so the problem is not specific to M2 macs. (To be more specific, I get that error with latex and xelatex, and a different error with pdflatex or lualatex; what are you using?)

Comment: i'm using LaTex dvips ps2pdf

Answer (score 1):

The error originated from the y-axis scaling. In this example, the scale was changed by  1000 factor and a matching label was added.

[image: z]

Using `lualatex` and `PSTricks v3.13  <2022/01/09>`. Also works with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=0.0005cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1000)(10.5,24000)
    \multido{\n=0.0000+0.3333}{32}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.2pt](\n,0)(\n,23000)}
    \multido{\n=0+1000}{24}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.2pt](0,\n)(10.5,\n)}
    \psaxes[linewidth=1.25pt, Dy=2, dy=1cm, ylabelFactor=\cdot10^3]{->}(0,0)(10.5,23500)% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \uput[r](0,23500){Nombre de mégots}
    \uput[d](9.25,-1200){Rang de l'année}
    \uput[d](10.5,-300){$x$}
    \uput[l](0,23000){$y$}
    \psdots[dotstyle=+,linecolor=red,dotscale=2](0,20000)(1,17384)(2,14817)(3,12569)(4,10721)(5,9142)(6,8458)(7,7673)(8,6691)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

On my system the error that appeared when using  `Dy=2000` and the upper y-limit was more than around 18500.

```
! Dimension too large.

(I can't work with sizes larger than about 19ft.)
```

See [! Dimension too large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139906/161015)

Now a secondary effect appeared: the y-ticks suffered a progressive displacement. So it's probably a bug. Or as the manual warns,

> `multido.tex` increments the labels using rudimentary fixed points
> arithmetic....

but why will the ticks be affected?

Comment: It works now. I will try a way to change now 2.10^3 by 2000.

Comment: thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Divide all y values by 1000 and then use `yLabelFactor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
    
\psset{yunit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10.5,24)
    \multido{\r=0.0000+0.3333}{32}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.2pt](\r,0)(\r,23)}
    \multido{\n=0+1}{24}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.2pt](0,\n)(10.5,\n)}
    \psaxes[linewidth=1.25pt,Dy=2,ylabelFactor=\cdot10^3]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(10.5,23)
    \uput[r](0,23.500){Nombre de mégots}\uput[d](9.25,-0.8){Rang de l'année}
    \uput[d](10.5,-0.300){$x$} \uput[l](0,23){$y$}
   \psdots[dotstyle=+,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,dotscale=2]%
      (0,20)(1,17.384)(2,14.817)(3,12.569)(4,10.721)(5,9.142)(6,8.458)(7,7.673)(8,6.691)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]